# Versioning of Visual Studio solution's common properties

Tags: git, visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2013

I would like to share certain properties of a solution with other members of my team. These properties include:

- Common Properties, e.g. Multiple Startup Projects
- Debug configuration, e.g. Command Line Arguments

As far as I know, this information is saved within the .suo file. However, versioning the .suo file is not feasible or recommended.

Is there any way to share the aforementioned information using Subversion / Git?